# Get total of hours on a day

Tags: java, date, parsing, calendar

Working with Java, I'm parsing a integer DAYS to HOURS.

Looks like this:

```
float hours = myvardays*24;
```

It works, but constant 24 is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), and best avoided.

Is there any constant on Calendar, Date or any other to get total hours in a day (24)? or maybe a method?

I am interested only in generic 24-hours, ignoring anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) that result in other day lengths.

Comment: I don't think that link has solution in java API

Comment: You can it self declare that as constant in your code

Comment: Are you worried about the transition to and from summer time?  Those days have 23 or 25 hours

Comment: No, I'm not. @DavidZimmerman

Comment: @Vrian7 Add clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. I did so for you here.

Comment: Since you are mentioning `Calendar` and `Date`, I recommend you don’t use those classes at all. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's not go reinventing stuff, this is all baked into the JDK:

## Java 8 and later

Use [`Duration.ofDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofDays-long-) with [`toDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toHours--) method.

```
long hours = Duration.ofDays(myvardays).toHours(); // Java 8+
```

## Java 5, 6, & 7

Use the [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum.

```
long hours = TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(myvardays); // Java 5+
```

Answer (score 2):

In JDK 8 you have the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class where you can perform conversions between units of time.

Example:

```
Duration.ofDays(1).toHours() //24hs
Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes() //60 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything in the Java Standard Libraries that does quite what you are looking for.

However if you have static numbers in your calculations there really is no reason to remove them. Unless you feel that they will change in the future or will need to be updated in many places should the needs of the application change (e.g. on mars where there may be a different number of hours in the day)

One could make an argument that it is unclear exactly what is going on (why 24, oh right...). You may want to make a small class containing your own constants with clear names simply to make the code more readable.

For example:

```java
public final class TimeIntervals {
    // ...
    public static final int HOURS_IN_DAY = 24;
    public static final int DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7;
    //...
}
```

and then use it as

```java
float hours = days * TimeIntervals.HOURS_IN_DAY;
```